# "Must specify grant_type field" error when getting Oauth2 token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, restify

I've got a simple **node.js** backend build on **Restify** with **OAuth2** authorization (restify-oauth2 plugin).

I've got a problem requesting a token. When I call POST method with my REST client, everything works correctly and I get `access_token` and `token_type`.

The problem occurs when I try to do the same thing in my frontend aplication made in **Angular**.

Here's my code:

```
 var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/token',
     headers: headers,
     data: {},
     params: {grant_type: "client_credentials"}
 };

 $http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
     console.log('success');
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
     console.log('error');
 });
```

So as you can see, `grant_type` parameter is provided. But still the server responds with:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Must specify grant_type field."}
```

And here's devtools screenshot:

[image]

How do I need to change my request to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. The thing is that grant_type field must be passed inside a request body, not in the parameters.

Working request code:

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/token',
  headers: headers,
  data: "grant_type=client_credentials"
};

$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
  console.log('success');
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
  console.log('error');
});
```